# Fingerprint scanner using camera of android device

Tags: android, image-processing, sdk

I m trying to implement, capture finger image and then scan that image and get the biometric fingerprints from that image and then finaly sending that image to server.
Basically i dont have idea to work on image processing of these. so i tried Onyx SDK and the problem solved. but its a trail version. Now i need to know what are the proces undergoes inorder to get biometic image of finger, like cropping, inverting, contrasting, etc .
Can anyone tell me the steps to undergone for image processing. Or anyother open source sdk for fingerprint sensor. Ur help is much appreciated.

I m just trying to do something like this. 
[image] [image]

say img one is captured image and imge two is after reconizing the biometric fingerprint

Comment: are you sure you can get such a good picture of a finger with the camera?

Comment: yes,i think so. since i used a sdk of Onyx i got good img and verification is validated

Comment: ok, cool, what I'd do at this point is: 1. crop just the finger tip part, 2. use edge detection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) to obtain something like the second image you posted, 3. use SIFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) to extract features form the fingerprint image so that they can be matched.

Comment: currently i dont have. can u tell   me Y?

Comment: oh thanks, but i dont have , so use above or i ll upload soon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is "match" two images of fingertips: one is the original image of the authorised user's fingertip and the other one is the image of the fingertip the camera just captured.

If the two images "match" then the camera captured the authorised user's fingertip and you shall let her in, otherwise access is to be denied.

Here's the steps I'd fallow to evaluate "matching" between to fingertip images:

1. **[Crop the essential part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image))**: you can crop an area at the center of the image, or put a square area in overlay on the CameraPreview and ask the user to capture the camera image when this square area is completely covered by her fingertip. Then crop out what's inside that square.
2. **[Equalize the cropped image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization)**: equalization gives more contrast and betters the image in general.
3. **[Detect edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection)**: by detecting edges you'll obtain something like the black and white image you posted, with only the fingerprint lines showing.
4. **[Apply SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform)**: with SIFT you extract "features" which are Scale-invariant (alsto rotation, tilt, light...-invariant) representations of points in your image. Using these features you can compare two images: they match if features can be found in both images.

---

## Let's give a little practical example

**Step 1: Original image**

Here's the original user's fingertip image

[image]

**Step 2: Cropping**

We crop it to just the fingertip

[image]

**Step 3: Equalization**

We equalize the cropped image

[image]

**Step 4: Edges**

We find the edges

[image]

Now we can save this image and keep it for future authentication reference.

**Step 5: New image captured**

When a new image of a fingertip is acquired by the camera

[image]

**Step 6: Process new image**

We process it just like the original one

[image]

**Step 7: Matching**

Finally we use SIFT to match the original image wit the new one

[image]

See that, even if some point is mismatched (10%), most of them (90%, the big central group) matches correctly. In this example SIFT finds 20 points of match, you could also set a threshold for feature quality which improves matches.

---

## With Android

To do all this stuff with Android, you could use the [OpenCV Android Library](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) which has utils for pretty much everything, [including SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html#gsc.tab=0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it helped me lot but, so i need to use opencv sdk adn then capture image and do these on tht img  1. Crop the essential part 2.Equalize the cropped image 3. Detect Edges 4. Apply SIFT: ?

Comment: You can do all these steps with OpenCV. Should be quite easy as it has specific methods for most of them.

Comment: hm, if u know any tutorial to work on fingerprint using open cv can give me link thq

Comment: here's one with another similar approach (it uses binarization + thinning + harris corner response): https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/fingerprint-detection-using-opencv-3